# Can the two female belts in Jurassic Park be anything else but a wrongly installed belt?

Tags: safety, aircraft-maintenance, seatbelts

In *Jurassic Park*, when the party arrives on Isla Nublar, Dr. Alan Grant discovers his seat belt has two female ends. He makes it work, foreshadowing that in nature as well, a population of only females can "make it work" — the dinosaurs are breeding!

How on earth can a seat with two female belts have ever passed inspection?

Or is there something else going on? I'm not familiar with the model of helicopter, but can there have been a mistake, where the people in the seats next to him — John Hammond and Dr. Ellie Sattler — took the wrong belt, leaving him with a female end where he should've had a male end?
Labeling the seats from A to D, with Dr. Grant in seat A, Dr. Sattler in seat B, and Hammond in C, and belts labeled F and M, is the following configuration possible in this model helicopter?

```
AF|Grant|BF|AM|Sattler|CF|BM|Hammond|DF|CM|empty|DM
```

That means the helicopter needs to have four seats in a row. Does this model *have* four seats in a row?
Or did Dr. Grant leave someone else with two male ends?

Is there another solution that explains why he failed to locate the correct belt? Or is there no excuse and should an anonymous mechanic have gotten a citation?

---

Basically, my question boils down to:

**Does this model helicopter have a configuration with four seats in a row?**

**If not, is there any other explanation other than a wrongly installed belt?**

Comment: He simply grabbed two of the wrong ends. Someone else is probably sitting on the other half.

Comment: "*How on earth can a seat with two female belts have ever passed inspection?*" I'm not an expert, but this was probably in the screenplay and no one was faulty.

Comment: It was an element of a Hollywood screenplay used for light comedy and to cement the idea of Sam Neil's character being mechanically inept but practical with the audience.

Comment: Sounds like a typical Hollywood [trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WomenAreWiser)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He has simply picked up  the end in his right hand which belongs to the belt of the person sitting on his right.

If you have two people sitting side by side with lap belts then there will be two belts in between them eg

**F**-(passengerA)-M-**F**-(passengerB)-M

As mentioned in the comments there is a good chance that he is siting on his own male-ended belt.

Comment: That's my suggestion, but that would need the helicopter to have 4 seats in a row. Does that model have that?

Comment: @SQB Why 4 in a row? The answer clearly shows it can happen with 2 and you can see in the video there is 3.

Comment: @Notts90 because the other two people are seated and belted correctly, which means there must be at least 4 female seat belt ends. So either at least 4 seats, or an FAA violation.

Comment: You don't actually see  that the other two people in the row do have their belts done up. In fact it looks like Sattler  can't find hers either (0:46)  then sees that  Grant has got two female buckles and realises what has happened. Hammond actually leans over to try to sort it out (1:05) which suggest that he hasn't got his on either ie Grant takes the wrong belt before Sattler has a chance to.

Comment: @SQB basically what Chris said above.

Comment: Of course since there is nowhere to walk in a helicopter, they should have been buckled up since before take-off and not hurriedly buckling up just before landing.

Comment: At 1:05 there is no seatbelt visible across Sattler's lap. Grant grabbed her end and his, making both belts unusable.

Comment: @ChrisJohns if you add your comment about the others in his row not being able to find _their_ belts because Grant took the wrong belts to your answer, I'll accept it. I don't feel comfortable editing it in myself.